# ListView filter for android

Tags: android, listview, filter, adapter

I've an adapter and and I use a  `ad.getFilter().filter(s);` for filter a listView.
It works well if I write a single word in EditText.
It doesn't work (result no row) if a write a space Character after a word.
I'd like to do a filter with name and surmane for example. 
I want to insert `"Mario Rossi"` in edittext and have a result..
I hope that I explained.
Thanks a lot.

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        ad.getFilter().filter(s);               
    }

};
```

Comment: See this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407428/filter-for-android-listview-space-character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code is perfect but some small mistake there

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              ad.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {


        }

    };
```