# Filter for android ListView - Space Character

Tags: java, android, listview, filter, adapter

I want to filter my `listView` using an `EditText` box and using the adapter `getFilter()` function. It works just fine until I put a space character in the text box.

Edit: It's a **SimpleAdapter not ArrayAdapter**

If my list contains these words: {"Apple", "Banana", "Red Apple"}
If I type "apple" it will return all the items containing the word apple in it (Apple and Red Apple).
If I type "apple " it won't returning anything.

Any ideas? Here's the code:

```
searchBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchBox);

searchBox.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
```

and

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
}
};
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: I haven't sorry. I think the solution might be to make your own adapter based on an ArrayAdapter but I haven't tried (stopped working on that project).

Comment: @CaptainProg What type of answer are you looking for? With the original question posed using `trim()` is the best answer.

Comment: @Chris911 I have a similar problem and I have posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573432/get-filter-does-not-work-for-space-in-android I hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the filtering functionality from SimpleAdapter doesn't fulfill your filtering requirements, you will need to override the SimpleAdapter and implement your own filtering requirements.

This requires a lot of code, as Filter in `SimpleAdapter` is using a lot of private objects, that you will need to replicate. The same aplies for `ArrayAdapter`

Fortunatly, someone else (@uʍop ǝpısdn) already went to the process, wrote the code and made it available for the community.

You can find the link to is blog [here](http://blogactivity.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/filterable-adapter/) including how to use examples, and the code in [here](https://github.com/slezica/blogActivity/blob/master/src/com/slezica/tools/widget/FilterableAdapter.java).

Regards.

Comment: I think this is the only valid solution. Been a while since I asked this question and I'm not working on that project anymore but I'll try to validate. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly. The described problem arises due to this line:
`String[] words = str.split(" ");` in **SimpleAdapter.SimpleFilter** class, which simply omits spaces from your initial Strings, splitting them into words.

Comment: @Luis I have a similar problem and I have posted a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573432/get-filter-does-not-work-for-space-in-android I hope you can help.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
myAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString().trim());
```

Comment: This only works partially because it removes spaces but let's say I type in "Red Ap" it will trim it to "RedAp" and there's not word in my selection containing "RedAp". So basically it does fix the issue if I put a single " " before or after a word but doesn't give the result I want.

Comment: @Chris911: it won't actually.trimming means,it simply removes space before and after the text starts and stops respectively.so if you will type "apple " then it will trim it to be "apple" but if you type "red ap",it will take it as it.got the point?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Hiral but that still doesn't fix the problem. I'm starting to think the only way to do this is to implement my own adapter with my own filter.