# how to choose different values together in filter

Tags: android, filter, adapter

I have:

```
adapter.getFilter().filter("changing value");
```

I want to filter by using `aa` and `bb` values together, but I can do it with the only one value. How can I use them together ?

for example:
1.`aa` 
2.`bb`
3.`cc`
4.`dd`
5.`ee`

adapter.getFilter().filter("`aa` and `dd`");

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13371160/2668136

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is wrong for my question.